# How to display a custom error page for HTTP status 405 (method not allowed) in Django when using @require_POST

Tags: django, http-status-codes, http-status-code-405

My question is simple, how do I display a custom error page for HTTP status 405 (method not allowed) in Django when using the `@require_POST` decorator?

I'm using the `django.views.decorators.http.require_POST` decorator, and when the page is visited by GET request, the console shows a 405 error, but the page is just blank (not even a Django error page). How do I get Django to display a custom and/or default error page for this kind of error?

EDIT:
It's worth mentioning that I've tried putting a 404.html, 500.html and 405.html page in my templates folder - but that does not help either. I have also varied between `DEBUG = True` and `False`, to no avail.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to write custom Django middleware. You can start with this one and extend it to check if 405.html file exists and so on:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseNotAllowed
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.template import loader


class HttpResponseNotAllowedMiddleware(object):
    def process_response(self, request, response):
        if isinstance(response, HttpResponseNotAllowed):
            context = RequestContext(request)
            response.content = loader.render_to_string("405.html", context_instance=context)
        return response
```

Check docs if you don't know how to install middleware:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/middleware/

You can also check this article:

http://mitchfournier.com/2010/07/12/show-a-custom-403-forbidden-error-page-in-django/

Comment: Thanks - it seems so obvious now! But quite a lot more trouble than I expected.

Comment: This was a helpful response but it no longer worked for me on Django 1.11. I had to use `response.content = loader.render_to_string("405.html", request=request)` and no longer could use (or had to use) the context.

Answer (score 0):

If you look into the [documentation](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/views/#customizing-error-views) and the source code of django.views.defaults you see that only 404 and 500 errors are supported in a way that you only have to add the 404.html resp. 500.html to your templates directory.

In the doc. you can also read the following

> Returning HTTP error codes in Django
>   is easy. There are subclasses of
>   HttpResponse for a number of common
>   HTTP status codes other than 200
>   (which means "OK"). You can find the
>   full list of available subclasses in
>   the request/response documentation.

Thus if you want to return a 405 error, you have to use the HttpResponseNotAllowed [class](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseNotAllowed)

An [example](http://nullege.com/codes/search/django.http.HttpResponseNotAllowed.write)

Comment: I'm afraid you're not answering the question - the problem isn't returning a 405 status - the problem is displaying a template for that response while using the @require_POST decorator.

Comment: You are right, missed the information you are using the decorator.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that's possible. Perhaps you should consider filing a bug report.

Comment: Well, we now know it is possible. But it is anything but as simple as adding a page for 404 and 500. Considering there's a built-in decorator for @require_POST etc, one would expect it to be easier.

Answer (score 0):

I landed here in 2022. The above accepted answer is not working for me. I use django rest framework. My sollution was to create a middleware with

```
#app/middleware.py

from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader

class HttpResponseNotAllowedMiddleware:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
    self.get_response = get_response
    # One-time configuration and initialization.

def __call__(self, request):
    
    # Code to be executed for each request before
    # the view (and later middleware) are called.

    response = self.get_response(request)

    # Code to be executed for each request/response after
    # the view is called.
    if response.status_code == 405:
        context = {}
        template = loader.get_template('app/405.html')
        return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))

    return response
```

then install it by adding this to settings

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
.......
'app.middleware.HttpResponseNotAllowedMiddleware',
]
```

the 405.html template is just a plain not allowed text